# Is there an STL way for getting the current thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, stl

I am currently working on desintegrating GLib functions from a large application.

In some functions, it uses the GLib function `g_thread_self()` which returns a pointer to the current thread.

I know that in the STL there is a `std::this_thread::get_id()` function but since I have a member variable which saves a pointer to a thread I want to be able to save a thread's address directly.

Is this possible in C++17?

Let's say I have a class MyThread (please mark that I did not write the logic of this source code):

```cpp
class MyThread {
public: 
    void startRoutine(MyThread* other)
    {
        // ...
        other->loop();

        // ...
        // here, I need to know if my thread is joinable
        if (other->_thread && other->_thread->joinable()) {
            other->thread = nullptr;
        }
    }
    bool isInsideCurrentThread() 
    {
        // `this_thread()` is the function I'm looking for
        return nullptr == _thread || this_thread() == _thread;
    };
    // ...

private:
    std::thread* _thread;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean with "thread's address" ? The actual threads are managed by the OS, the id is perhaps the best you can get as an adress. It would be bad if you could get a `std::thread` from the current thread, because then it would be possible to have two `std::thread` managing the same thread.

Comment: [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? What would you do with that adress if you could get one? Maybe there is a different way to solve your actual problem

Comment: I get your point. Apparently the class I'm working in is constantly doing owner and caller checks which would be possible to solve using only the id, but it also checks if a thread is joinable, which is something I can't achieve with just an `id` given.

Comment: `g_thread_self()` returns a pointer to a GLib struct which holds a copy of the thread id.  The GLib struct is not the "thread's address", it's just an address to the GLib struct.  [`std::thread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) can be used to see if a thread is joinable.

Comment: Not sure if I understand, From within the thread you know that it is joinable, unless it is detached.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I have edited my question so maybe you understand it a bit better now.

Comment: no sorry, I still dont understand. "`this_thread()` is the function I'm looking for" at that place you can compare `_thread->get_id()` with `this_thread::get_id()`. Actually I dont understand what `isInsideCurrentThread` is supposed to be, some code that is executed is always in the current thread

Comment: if you want to know if the current thread is `_thread` you can compare their ids, why not?

Comment: OK let me ask it differently: if I only have a thread's id, can I somehow find out if this thread is joinable?

Comment: If thats your actual question you should include it in the question. Though i still dont get it completely. The current thread is either detached or joinable. Are you sure thats what you need to know?

Comment: @taiBsu what circumstances do you expect to encounter that would make the thread not joinable?

Answer (score 1):

No, as of C++17 (or 20) there is no standard way to obtain a pointer to a `std::thread` instance managing the current thread.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no standard function that would return a pointer to a `std::thread` wrapper that refers to the current thread.

You could use an associative container to map the native id to the `std::thread` object, but that's not necessary to implement the example function. You can implement it like this:

```
bool isInsideCurrentThread() 
{
    return std::this_thread::get_id() == _thread->get_id();
};
```

Comment: Thanks, I know about this. However, I would still need a different thread's ability to be joinable, and on the other hand be able to save a certain thread's address inside the same variable.

Comment: @taiBsu `I would still need a different thread's ability to be joinable` That's what the `std::thread::joinable` is for.